# SunPKCS11 is removing duplicate key entries

Tags: java, sunpkcs11

I'm using SunPKCS11 security provider to store key entries (certificate + private key) into a nShield HSM using the `setKeyEntry` method but when I store the same certificate with different aliases the first one is removed from de HSM. I've tested with soft HSM too but I get the same behaviour.

I found this in [PKCS#11 Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/pkcs11-reference-guide1.htm) but I'm not storing CA certificates, they are user certificates:

> "If a CA certificate is already in the token, a duplicate is not stored."

Is possible to store the same certificate (and private key) with different aliases using SunPKCS11 security provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s a Sun PKCS#11 implementation bug:

https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8264099

Additionally I am forced to use a vendor specific implementation to avoid performance issues.